# Argument of complex number with a variable

Tags: scripting

I want to evaluate the following expression

```
Arg[E^((0. + 6.66667*10^-12 I) omega)/(4 - E^((0. + 2.*10^-11 I) omega))]
```

where the variable omega is real and positive.

I have tried

```
$Assumptions = {omega \[Element] Reals, omega > 0}
Simplify[ComplexExpand[expression above]]
```

But it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give [`ComplexExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand) a [`TargetFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TargetFunctions) option, and use [`FullSimplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify) instead:

```
FullSimplify[
    ComplexExpand[
        Arg[E^((0.+6.66667*10^-12 I) omega)/(4-E^((0.+2.*10^-11 I) omega))],
        TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}
    ],
    omega \[Element] Reals && omega > 0
]
```

> ArcTan[4. Cos[6.66667*10^-12 omega] - 1. Cos[1.33333*10^-11 omega], 
>    4. Sin[6.66667*10^-12 omega] + 1. Sin[1.33333*10^-11 omega]]

Comment: Thanks! It works :)