# Arg function very slow

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

In this thread [Argument of complex number with a variable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/161009/argument-of-complex-number-with-a-variable/161010#161010) I asked the question how to get the phase of a complex expression with one single real and positive variable.

In principle this is solved but if I want to get the phase of a more complicated expression what takes forever and I have to abort the evaluation.
For example:

```
T=-E^((0. - 1.33333*10^-10 I) omega) (1/3 E^((0. + 1.2*10^-10 I) omega) (4/3 E^((0. + 6.66667*10^-12 I) omega) - 1/3 E^((0. - 1.33333*10^-11 I) omega)) + 2/3 E^((0. + 6.*10^-11 I) omega) (2/3 E^((0. - 6.66667*10^-12 I) omega) -2/3 E^((0. + 1.33333*10^-11 I) omega))) + 2 E^((0. + 6.66667*10^-11 I) omega) (2/
 3 E^((0. - 6.*10^-11 I) omega) (4/
    3 E^((0. + 6.66667*10^-12 I) omega) - 
   1/3 E^((0. - 1.33333*10^-11 I) omega)) + 
1/3 E^((0. - 1.2*10^-10 I) omega) (2/
    3 E^((0. - 6.66667*10^-12 I) omega) - 
   2/3 E^((0. + 1.33333*10^-11 I) omega))) - ((2 E^((0. - 
      6.66667*10^-11 I) omega) (1/
      3 E^((0. + 1.2*10^-10 I) omega) (4/
         3 E^((0. + 6.66667*10^-12 I) omega) - 
        1/3 E^((0. - 1.33333*10^-11 I) omega)) + 
     2/3 E^((0. + 6.*10^-11 I) omega) (2/
         3 E^((0. - 6.66667*10^-12 I) omega) - 
        2/3 E^((0. + 1.33333*10^-11 I) omega))) - 
  E^((0. + 1.33333*10^-10 I) omega) (2/
      3 E^((0. - 6.*10^-11 I) omega) (4/
         3 E^((0. + 6.66667*10^-12 I) omega) - 
        1/3 E^((0. - 1.33333*10^-11 I) omega)) + 
     1/3 E^((0. - 1.2*10^-10 I) omega) (2/
         3 E^((0. - 6.66667*10^-12 I) omega) - 
        2/3 E^((0. + 1.33333*10^-11 I) omega)))) (-E^((0. - 
       1.33333*10^-10 I) omega) (1/
      3 E^((0. + 1.2*10^-10 I) omega) (2/
         3 E^((0. + 6.66667*10^-12 I) omega) - 
        2/3 E^((0. - 1.33333*10^-11 I) omega)) + 
     2/3 E^((0. + 6.*10^-11 I) omega) (4/
         3 E^((0. - 6.66667*10^-12 I) omega) - 
        1/3 E^((0. + 1.33333*10^-11 I) omega))) + 
  2 E^((0. + 6.66667*10^-11 I) omega) (2/
      3 E^((0. - 6.*10^-11 I) omega) (2/
         3 E^((0. + 6.66667*10^-12 I) omega) - 
        2/3 E^((0. - 1.33333*10^-11 I) omega)) + 
     1/3 E^((0. - 1.2*10^-10 I) omega) (4/
         3 E^((0. - 6.66667*10^-12 I) omega) - 
        1/3 E^((0. + 1.33333*10^-11 I) omega)))))/(2 E^((0. - 
    6.66667*10^-11 I) omega) (1/
    3 E^((0. + 1.2*10^-10 I) omega) (2/
       3 E^((0. + 6.66667*10^-12 I) omega) - 
      2/3 E^((0. - 1.33333*10^-11 I) omega)) + 
   2/3 E^((0. + 6.*10^-11 I) omega) (4/
       3 E^((0. - 6.66667*10^-12 I) omega) - 
      1/3 E^((0. + 1.33333*10^-11 I) omega))) - 
E^((0. + 1.33333*10^-10 I) omega) (2/
    3 E^((0. - 6.*10^-11 I) omega) (2/
       3 E^((0. + 6.66667*10^-12 I) omega) - 
      2/3 E^((0. - 1.33333*10^-11 I) omega)) + 
   1/3 E^((0. - 1.2*10^-10 I) omega) (4/
       3 E^((0. - 6.66667*10^-12 I) omega) - 
      1/3 E^((0. + 1.33333*10^-11 I) omega))))
```

and doing something like

```
ArgT = FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[Arg[T], TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}],omega \[Element] Reals && omega > 0];
```

will take more than 3 minutes on my machine. Can you recommencement me a quicker way? Basically this should be very straight forward and I don't know why this should take so much time? In the future my terms will be even larger so I need a solution.

Furthermore after the step which I described above I want to plot the derivative

```
D[ArgT, omega]
```

and this is only possible if I have an analytic expression...

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You should simplify your expression as much as you can. Try `FullSimplify[T] // ExpToTrig // Chop // 
   ComplexExpand[Arg[#], TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & // 
  Chop // Simplify`. I have noted that your result has very small numbers, and is almost constant. I do not know if this what you are expecting. Oh, the operation is fast in my machine (i3, macOS 10.13.1, MMA 11.2).

Comment: I mean it depends on how large omega is... You mean without the simplifications the computation is fast?

Comment: I mean (and I am assuming) that omega must be quite large. And, yes, it is fast after a first simplification, as you can see in the order of the functions applied...

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of an answer to an old question:

(1) `FullSimplify` works extra hard, and sometimes extra long.  With elementary functions, `Simplify` usually works hard enough and is faster.

(2) One should look at `T // Together`: It's a lot simpler already.

```
argT = Simplify[
      ComplexExpand[Arg@Together@T, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}], 
      omega \[Element] Reals && omega > 0] /. 
    z_Complex /; Im[z] == 0 :> Re[z]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.295009, Null}  *)

(* probably not necessary, but fast: *)
argT = TrigReduce /@ argT // Simplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]